# How do I get my session token data across to different Javascript files from the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session

So, this is the current state of my session tokens on my server:

server.js:

```
app.use(
    session({
        secret: "{}",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
    })
);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/webpages/CurrentProjects/currentProjects.html");
    const username = req.session.username;
    console.log(username);
});
```

Is there anyway to get the req.session.username data across all the javascript files in my web application so I can access the username variable anywhere in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway to get the req.session.username data across all the javascript files in my web application so I can access the username variable anywhere in my project?

You will need to pass the username as a function argument to other functions in other modules in your project that want to use it.

It cannot be stored in a global variable to be easily accessible everywhere because there can be multiple requests in flight at the same time and putting request-specific data into a global will cause the data to get overwritten and will confused one request's data with another.

So, if you want to call some function in another module from within your request handler, you can either pass the session or pass the username as a function argument and then let that function get the data from the function argument.

If you have a whole group of functions that want access to the username, then it is sometimes more convenient to make those functions all methods on an object and then you can instantiate one of those objects passing the username to the constructor and then any of those methods that want access to the username can get it from the object's instance data.  But, whether or not this is appropriate depends on the specific code and structure.

Comment: How do I do that? Whenever I write a global function serving both the Server and Client to get the username across from server to client, I come across errors like `require` not defined on my client side when I try to require the function js file.

Comment: @CodeBlaze - All I suggested was that you define a function on your server that accepts `username` as a function argument.  That has nothing at all to do with how you write code that can be run on both client and server - that would be a completely different question and would require seeing exactly what code you're trying to use on both client and server.  Please write a new and different question for that.  I think I've answered what you originally asked here.

Comment: @CodeBlaze - Perhaps you don't realize, but the client and server do not share the same variables at all.  If you want access to the username in your client-side Javascript, then you will have to insert that info into your web page on the server so that the client-side Javascript can access that info from it's own code or set a cookie that indicates the username and have the client code get it from the cookie.

Comment: yeah, I couldn't get that to work. Got the data sharing done through cookies though so that helped. Thanks!